# ros_canopen vel_from_device: (obj606C) issue

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am using the `ros_canopen` package to communicate with a `BGE 6010` controller manufactured by `Dunkermotoren`.

My problem is that the manufacturer did not implement `606C` object in their controller. (i contacted them and they confirmed)

So in the configuration `yaml` file the following line gives error:

```
vel_from_device: "(obj606C)*2*pi/60"
```

Error string:

> abort606c#0, reason: Object does not
> exist in the object dictionary.

Instead of the 606C object, the controller provides the object: `3A04.01h`, which is also the velocity measurement in rpm. Unfortunately, if i put

```
vel_from_device: "(obj3A04)*2*pi/60"
```

then i get the error:

```
[ERROR] [1565873540.254325002]: Could not find variable 'obj3A04', reason: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/canopen_master/objdict.h(224): Throw in function const EntryConstSharedPtr& canopen::ObjectDict::at(const canopen::ObjectDict::Key&) const
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::out_of_range> >
std::exception::what: Unable to find key in unordered_map.
[canopen::tag_objectdict_key*] = 3a04
```

**Is there any workaround to solve this issue?**

Remark:
I map the aforementioned actual velocity to PDO as:

```
   "1A01sub0": "2" #
    "1A01sub1": "0x60640020" #            
    "1A01sub2": "0x3A040120" #
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330785/ros_canopen-vel_from_device:-(obj606c)-issue/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Unfortunately, if i put vel_from_device: "(obj3A04)*2*pi/60" then i get the error:

It looks like `3A04` is a struct/record. In this case you cannot use it as a variable.

> 3A04.01h which is also the velocity measurement in rpm

Try something like

```
vel_from_device: "obj3A04sub1*2*pi/60"
```

(`sub1` corresponds to `.01h`.)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-08-15**:
@Mathias Lüdtke thank you for the help! I will try it tomorrow and come back here. `However` i don't get the formula you recommended: `2*pi/obj3A04sub1`.

If i understand correctly: `obj3A04sub1` gives the velocity in RPM, then it is converted into SI (rad/sec) by multiplying it by 2*pi/60, not? I dont get why did you use the inverse?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-08-15**:
Yep, you're right, I was somehow mistaken.

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-08-16**:
vel_from_device: "obj3A04sub1*2*pi/60"

works like a charm. Thanks again!